# Vue component not updating when array is changed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

A user is able to enter their username and when they press the button, their stats are retrieved from a high scores API for this game. In my data I have the following:

```
data () {
    return {
      skills: [[["Attack", 0], ["Hitpoints", 0], ["Mining", 0]], 
      [["Strength", 0], ["Agility", 0], ["Smithing", 0]],
      [["Defence", 0], ["Herblore", 0], ["Fishing", 0]],
      [["Ranged", 0], ["Thieving", 0], ["Cooking", 0]],
      [["Prayer", 0], ["Crafting", 0], ["Firemaking", 0]],
      [["Magic", 0], ["Fletching", 0], ["Woodcutting", 0]], 
      [["Runecrafting", 0], ["Slayer", 0], ["Farming", 0]], 
      [["Construction", 0], ["Hunter", 0], ["Overall", 0]]],
      selectedArr: [],
      username: "",
    }
},
```

So a big array storing the stats in rows of three. The stat name followed by the amount of experience they have in that particular skill. So initially the experience is set to 0.

I call the next two functions when the user enters their username and clicks the button:

```
createurl: function() {
  const url = "http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/index_lite.ws?player=" + this.username;
  this.getuserdata(url);
},
getuserdata: function(d) {
  let skillsArrCopy = this.skills;
  this.$http.post('http://localhost:8888/getuserdata.php', {url: d},
   {emulateJSON: true}).then(response => {
     const data = JSON.parse(response.bodyText);
     for(let i=0; i<skillsArrCopy.length; i++) {
       for(let j=0; j<3; j++) {
         skillsArrCopy[i][j][1] = parseInt(data[skillsArrCopy[i][j][0]]);
       }
     }
     this.skills = skillsArrCopy;
   });
}
```

This calls a php file that returns the stats and updates the array. I KNOW THAT THIS WORKS RIGHT NOW. I have the vue development tools and can see that the array gets updated. i.e the 0's update to the amount of experience the user has.

The issue I am having is that this does not update on the page, unless I do another action. e.g. click on stat (which changes the color of it in the table). Here is the html for this section:

```
<table cellspacing="0">
    <tr v-for="(value, key) in skills">
      <td v-on:click="changeSelectedArr(value[0][0])" v-bind:class="{ selected: selectedArr.indexOf(value[0][0]) > -1 }">
        <img v-bind:src="geturl(value[0][0])"/>
        <div class="level">{{ skills[key][0][1] }}</div>
      </td>
      <td v-on:click="changeSelectedArr(value[1][0])" v-bind:class="{ selected: selectedArr.indexOf(value[1][0]) > -1 }">
        <img v-bind:src="geturl(value[1][0])"/>
        <div class="level">{{ skills[key][1][1] }}</div>
      </td>
      <td v-on:click="changeSelectedArr(value[2][0])" v-bind:class="{ selected: selectedArr.indexOf(value[2][0]) > -1 }">
        <img v-bind:src="geturl(value[2][0])"/>
        <div class="level">{{ skills[key][2][1] }}</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So the array is getting updated, but it does not update on the page. The only way it updates, is if I do another action (By clicking the table cell which changes the colour of it). This triggers the update for some reason. How can I make it so the page updates when the array does?

Comment: @Ferrybig Second line in the getuserdata() function

Comment: Your problem is caused by [a common VueJS pitfall](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/#Why-isn%E2%80%99t-the-DOM-updating) Update your array using `skillsArrCopy[i][j].$set(1, parseInt(data[skillsArrCopy[i][j][0]]))`

Comment: @Ferrybig I got an error once doing that: Quest.vue?6f5f:68 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: skillsArrCopy[i][j].$set is not a function

Comment: The syntax is incorrect, use: `this.$set(skillsArrCopy[i][j], 1, parseInt(data[skillsArrCopy[i][j][0]]))` - See: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats